# Camel or Pascal for Method Fields or Parameters Coding Standard

Tags: c#

What is best practice for method fields or parameters (Camel or Pascal):

```
public string DoSomething(string documentName, string firstName)
{
    return string.Empty;    
}

public string DoSomething(string DocumentName, string FirstName)
{
    return string.Empty;    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `camelCasing` for parameter names. So option number 1 is correct.
It is actually not even a matter of opinion, as seen by the msdn link provided in the comments:

[image: camelPascal]